# How do you prevent a NET USER /domain vulnerability?

Tags: networking, cmd.exe, user

I discovered a vulnerability in my network;

(bear with me as I'm only about 2 weeks into the job and still in training).

Any end point user (regardless of permissions) can issue a NET USER /domain command and view all the users on the domain. Even if command prompt access is disabled, this can be worked around by creating a notepad file with COMMAND.COM and creating a batch file. We can't disable batch files as they are used heavily by end point users for normal tasks.

Unfortunately this command shows all the usernames of our various test accounts. A lot of these test accounts have very basic passwords and often have the same passwords as usernames. There are quite literally hundreds of these test accounts and it would be very inconvenient to change the passwords/delete the obselete accounts.

A lot of these test accounts have elevated/admin privileges (don't ask me why, seems like a massive breach in the making).

Is there some way you can prevent the net user /domain command from being run? I know you can audit who has run domain queries but this doesn't really prevent the vulnerability.

Comment: Honestly I think you need to fix the test accounts as that’s the real problem. There are other ways to see them without the command line - examples are the file permissions dialog or the Search Active Directory tool built into Windows.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll push for that to get done asap.

Comment: @JamesP nails it. This is not really a vulnerability (I mean the net user command) but having that many test accounts with high privileges is a huge deal. The moment you open up to the internet for stuff like VPN or RDP, you are basically asking to be hacked, and automated scanning bots will definitely defeat your line of defense easily enough to get big problems.

Answer (score -1):

Guidance on how to limit this: https://www.adamcouch.co.uk/disable-domain-user-enumeration/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1159627)